# UV Editing on NurbsPath

Tags: modeling, uv

Today I was trying to add a mustache onto my piece by using Nurbspath.I have never used it before and can't find a tutorial on how to use UV editing on it.I'm quite new to Blender and need help figuring out what to do.[image: Help!!]

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the answer which is completely valid, here is some additional information: another way to make a mesh object would be to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply* > *Visual Geometry to Mesh*.

Both methods, this one and <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Convert to* > *Mesh*, work on curve and mesh objects. On a mesh object this only makes sense if you have modifiers on the object like *Subdivision Surface*, *Bevel*, *Displacement* and so on. They will automatically be applied in this case.

However, and here is a big difference between curve and mesh objects, if you convert a mesh object with modifiers, **all** the modifiers are applied, which means the geometry is changed according to the modifiers' settings and they are removed afterwards.

If you convert a curve to a mesh which also has a *Subdivision Surface* modifier added, then the conversion will only make a mesh object out of the base curve object and the modifier will be removed **without** applying. Which means, after converting to a mesh the smoothness is gone because the modifier is removed without affecting the mesh. And applying the modifier to a curve before converting to a mesh is not possible.

But this only happens if the *Subdivision Surface* modifier is the last in line. If you add e.g. a *Mirror* or *Simple Deform* modifier **after** the *Subdivision Surface*, everything will be applied. If the other modifiers are before (over) the *Subdivision Surface* modifier in the list, the conversion will only keep the mirrored and deformed mesh, but not the smoothing.

Answer (score 1):

To unwrap UVs, you must first convert your curve to a mesh.
Right-click and select Convert to > Mesh.